# Typescript creating an array of rules and getting

Tags: arrays, typescript, vue.js

I am just starting out with Typescript in vue.js.  I am trying to create an array of rules to validate an email.

in my data portion I have the following code

```
data(): {
    loading:  boolean,
    valid: boolean,
    emailRules: any[],
} {  
    return {
        loading: false,
        valid: true,
        emailRules: [
            v => !!v || "Email is required",
            v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "Email must be valid"
        ],
    }
},
```

I am getting a Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type error for the code above.  I figured because it is a rule I could use any for my array type but I am wrong.  So type should my array be so I don't have this error?

Comment: It complains about the function parameter `v`, which I think should be a string in this case, so you can change your rules to `v: string => ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should type the `v` payload like :

```js
        emailRules: [
            (v : string) => !!v || "Email is required",
            (v : string) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "Email must be valid"
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of v being a string.  I added :string and the error disappeared.